# Combining javascript files on the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, node.js, express

Just like you can extend html pages on the server. I wanted to know if there is any method to join javascript files on the server using node and express or any thing else that works with node. So as to minimize the number of files i have to link to the document and as well as keeping javascript files separate from each other.

Comment: There sure is, just make a route and link it to a function that gets the contents of the files, joins it together, and serves it all together.

Answer (score 1):

In fact it's better doing it once before deploying your js files on your server, to get better performances, than doing it on runtime.

You may do this with tools like [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) and the task [grunt-usemin](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin)
It will not only allow you to concatenate your files, but also to compress with uglify.